# How do I find out the IP address of my Pi?

Tags: networking, ssh, setup, connection, putty

So I do not have an HDMI monitor or any monitors around but I do have a computer with an ethernet port and I know that I can SSH to my pi via putty but the problem is that I do not know how to get the IP address of my pi from another windows 7 computer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

You don't mention which OS you are using, but there area couple of ways to do this:

1. You can try `ssh pi@raspberrypi` or `ssh raspberrypi.local` (this will may need to be adjusted if not using Raspbian - the first part is the username (pi) the second is the host name).
2. You can login to your router and check the device list.
3. You can ping the entire subnet using the following from the windows command prompt using `FOR /L %I in (1,1,255) DO PING 192.168.1.%I -n 1 -w 100 >> pung.txt` This will write the output to a file called pung.txt which contains the results of pinging each address in the subnet. depending on your PC's Ip address you may need to modify the subnet part of the above command (192.168.1) to match your local network.
4. You can search the arp cache; from the windows command prompt enter the following `arp -a` this will give you the list of all resolved devices on the network, turning the Pi off and rerunning the test should show you which IP is associated with your Pi (though unlikely, this may not always work as the Pi's IP may not have been cached yet).

Comment: For 3. you should note that this is for LANs that use the 192.168.y.x where Y=1 network - although this is commonly used, there are cases where Y can be 0 to 254(?) - (my first modem/router used 0!)

Comment: Also for users of *nix based OSs wanting to do "3." you may find: `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print ip}'` useful, it uses `nmap` to scan all the hosts on the local and report using the formatted output of `awk` any that have a MAC corresponding to a Pi's **wired Ethernet** port - you could drop in the MAC for a WiFi adapter IF you know it, to find THAT...