# SSH Error: Connection timed out : RPi

Tags: raspbian

I am new Raspberry pi user, recently while exploring , I did a remote shutdown of my Rpi with `sudo halt` command, since then I am not able to connect the Rpi remotely from my windows machine using putty , when ever I try , I get **Network Error: Connection timedout** error. I guess I have set a Static ip address, as I have not change any configuration to enable DHCP server.

Comment: Have you unplugged and replugged the pi? It won't boot again until you do so you won't connect because the pi is 'off'

Comment: yes.. I have replugged pi as will rebooted pi several times

Comment: Have you checked whether the IP address has changed??? Running sudo halt isn't going affect anything unless you don't turn it back on :p unless you set a static IP routers can change the IP of a device especially if while the device has been off it's issued it's previous IP to another device. I'd have a look on your router and make sure the IP is correct. Failing that hook it up to a monitor and have a look on the pi to see what network it's connecting to or if any errors are appearing.

Comment: Do you have set a static ip address on the RasPi or do you use a DHCP server on your network?

Comment: I guess I have set a Static ip address, as i have not change any configuration to enable DHCP server

Comment: Your question popped up again. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote you do not have made any changes to enable using a DHCP server. On Raspbian this is the default setting out of the box. If you do not changed any settings on the network configuration then the RasPi will get an ip address from a DHCP server that is very often presented by the (internet) router. if a DHCP server isn't found the RasPi will use a [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) that can be addressed with `raspberrypi.local`.

Seems you have found the ip address from the first boot so you could connect to it. But with a reboot it is possible that the RasPi gets a new ip address. It's now up to you to find the new ip address. Here are many answers about to [find ip address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=find+ip+address). One that may help you I have found at [How do I find out the IP address of my Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40043/79866). Have also a look at the comments on that answer.